# Show that $X\subset X\cup\left\{ X\right\}$

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

- Show that If $X$ is an any set, then $X\subset X\cup\left\{ X\right\}$

Proof. Let $t\in X$. We must show $t\in X\cup\left\{ X\right\}$, that is we need to show either $t\in X$ or $t\in\left\{ X\right\}$, so we know that $t\in X$, hence we are done.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: Is so simple that any more explanation just would make it clumsy. It is fine. A little thing: change that "so" by "but".

Comment: Ehm. Well. You're perfectly right. But the question unsettles me a little. :D

Comment: @YoungMath the questin was from my exam. I think It is very trivially but I see that the question don't says that $X\subseteq X\cup\left\{X\right\}$, from this do we get any problem?

Comment: Can we say $t\in X\subset X$?

Comment: @KathySong Yes, $\subset$ makes a difference. You need to show $\exists a\in X\cup\{X\}$ such that $a\notin X$. That $a$ is $X$

Comment: Oh well, that's subtile, you're right. Then, you need to show that $X \neq X \cup \{X\}$. However, this is simple since $X \notin X$ due to the axiom of regularity.

Comment: @YoungMath You said that it is simple but I couldn't show can you help? I couldn't use axiom of reg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, an answer on ground level of set theory is needed here. Since the inclusion $X \subseteq X \cup \{X\}$ is already discussed in full detail, I want to make a remark about the case $X \neq X \cup \{X \}$.

The *Axiom of Regularity* reads
$$ \forall x \left( x \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \exists y \in x: y \cap x = \emptyset \right).$$

Let us prove, that $X \notin X$ for all sets $X$.

Soo, let $X$ be any set. Due to the axiom of pairing, $\{X\}$ is a set aswell and clearly not empty (well, $X$ is an element). But in consequence of the axiom of regularity, we must have $X \cap \{X\} = \emptyset$ since $X$ is the **only** element in $\{X\}$. Hence, $X \notin X$.

Comment: Thank you for answer :)

Answer (score -1):

Exercise.
Show for all sets A and B, that A $\subseteq$ A $\cup$ B.

With that, your problem is just a special case.

Comment: Thanks for exercise. I would like to ask a question that how can I show $X\neq X\cup\left\{X\right\}$ Can you help?

Comment: @KathySong.  Equality would lead to X in X in contradiction to axiom of regularity.

Comment: Please read the comments before posting an answer. Thank you! :)